# Prevent HTML table from resizing to fit contents

Tags: html, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/GUSE5/5/

What I want is that each row has the height 33% of the table height, regardless of contents and that the image resize to fit the cell, but without losing proportions.

```
<table class="container"><tr><td>
<table class="contents" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
              Top content
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersview.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/free-nature-backgrounds-wallpapers.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Bottom content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
```

CSS:

```
table.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

table.contents {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

table.contents tr {
    height: 33%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You may need to think about copyright issues as well

Comment: The image is just an example. I use different images in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Set the height of the cell:

```
table.contents td {
    height: 33%;
}
```

Set the cell to be relatively positioned, so that we can use absolute positioning inside it:

```
table.contents td {
    height: 33%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Set your image to have `max-width` and `max-height` of `100%`. Also set it to have absolute positioning, and anchor it to the top-left corner:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Seems to work. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/thUeA/)

**Edit: This doesn't work in Firefox! A fix coming up:**

Set the height of the `tr` to `33%`:

```
table.contents tr {
    height: 33%;
}
```

Set the inner `td` to be a `block` element and have `100%` height; give it relative positioning:

```
table.contents td {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Set your image to have `max-width` and `max-height` of `100%`. Also set it to have absolute positioning, and anchor it to the top-left corner:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Should work! [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/64uY8/)

Comment: Oh dear! What do you mean by "go crazy"? I'll see if I can fix. Edit: Oh, wow, it really does go crazy. One moment while I fix.

Answer (score -1):

I think you looking to remove extra space from content, so content (text or img )look like  fitting in table cell, so i suggest remove this from css :

```
table.contents {
/* width: 100%;
height: 100%;  */  
}
```

Comment: No, I really want that the contents table entirely fit the container.